# How to convert model.module.fc when using DP, if using DDP

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, python-multiprocessing, distributed-system

When I try to use it, an error appears saying that there are no attributes. Do I have to use it in a different way when using ddp?

Comment: how about some code it goes a long way when it comes to debuging

Comment: try printing out the pytorch model out and see the model structure

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.